# Ext CalendarPanel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, calendar, ext.net

Am using Ext.net and vb.net CodeBehind

In CalendarPanel:

```
<DirectEvents>
<EventClick OnEvent="getCommand" >
</EventClick>
```

On event click I need to get the EventId in vb,
What am looking for is something similar to this Event:

```
<DayClick OnEvent="AddAppointment" Before="extraParams.date = dt;>
</DayClick>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use ExtraParams.

**EventClick markup**

```
<EventClick OnEvent="EventClick">
    <ExtraParams>
        <ext:Parameter Name="EventId" Value="record.data.EventId" Mode="Raw" />
    </ExtraParams>
</EventClick>
```

**EventClick handler**

```
protected void EventClick(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
{
    X.Msg.Alert("EventClick", e.ExtraParams["EventId"]).Show();
}
```